# kendo spreadsheet paste rows more than default 200

Tags: copy-paste, kendospreadsheet

thanks everbody.
I am using kendo spreadsheet and now encounter a problem. When user copies data from Excel to kendo spreadsheet, if the data rows greater than default 200, it would show "copy area and paste area is not the same size".

I tried to find out the event before paste and increase the rows number, but unlucky I can't find. The thing is I can't anticipate how many rows the user would copy.

Is there anyway can plug-in Kendo spreadsheet clipboard module to increase the rows number accordingly instead of throwing a warning message.

thank you very much.

Jason